# Run software when USB is connected

Tags: windows, usb

I am looking for a way to run software that is stored on a windows machine when a usb device is connected. Similar to how an antivirus program would scan it to make sure it is safe before allowing access. Is there an api or other way that you can do that? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this link will help you: [Detecting Media Insertion or Removal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa363215(v=vs.110))